# choosing the suitable DC motors

Tags: dc-motor, torque, brushless-dc-motor

I'm working on a 4x4 robot that is supposed to carry stuff `total_mass=100kg` (including the robot).
the robot should have average speed `20km/h`
assume that `inclination_angle=0` `acceleration=0.5m/s^2` `wheel_diameter=0.25m`
`direct drive (no gears)` `4 motors 4 wheels`

What kind of DC motors should i use (brushed or brushless or other)?
what are their properties? (torque, rpm ... combination)

I'm not so good at math and conversions.

Comment: You're going to need to get better at math and conversions :-) It's not about speed and mass, without any resisting forces the tiniest motor can get any mass to any speed.  What accelerations are you looking for?  How steep of an incline is the robot expected to traverse?  You need to know a lot more about the application before you pick motors.  I would say regardless of all this brushless is almost certainly the technology of choice if we're talking electrical.

Comment: When you face something like this and don't know where to start, find something similar - ie, other people's documented projects, or look at outdoor-mobility electric wheelchairs.  That will give you a good starting point / sanity check for your conclusions.

Comment: thanks @GuySirton, i'm trying to find the minimum requirements then i'll go up from there, so we can assume that `inclination_angle=0` and `acceleration=0.5m/s^2`

Comment: @ChrisStratton that's what i did exactly, i found electric wheelchairs the closest to my case,
the thing is wheelchairs are 2WD, in my case it's 4WD.
and i don't really know how is force and torque distributed, and couldn't find the right terms, so googling didn't help

Comment: @mabdrabo: OK.  So we know F=ma right?  So 0.5*100kg = 50N.  4x4, are you going to have a motor per wheel?  What is the diameter of your wheels?  Are you planning to direct drive or use a gear box?  Torque is given in Newton-Meter so that would be the force one meter away...

Comment: yes 4 motors 1 per wheel,
`wheel_diameter=0.25m`,direct drive.
so this means i'll need 4 50Nm motors?

Comment: can you please tell me why do i need the 4 motors to be 100Nm, if only 1 motor 100Nm is able to do the job? i mean why isn't it divided or something?

Comment: @GuySirton: Your math needs some work, too. A 100 N-m motor provides 200 N of force at the rim of a 0.5 m radius wheel, not 50 N. If the total force required for the robot is 50 N, and you have 4 motors, that's 50 / 4 = 12.5 N per motor. If the wheels have a radius of 0.125 m (diameter = 0.25 m), then the torque required per motor is 12.5 N * 0.125 m = 1.5625 N-m.

Comment: @DaveTweed: You're right!  It's been a while...  It's the physics not the math though :-)

Comment: You might also consider asking this over at the [Robotics Stackexchange](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: With .5m/s^2 max acceleration I hope you don't have to deal with hills, or even 1/12 slope wheelchair ramps.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, i'm just trying to know the minimum to make it move, then increasing anything will make it better accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's work out the basic physics of the situation (note this assumes the rotating mass is zero, a reasonable first approximation for this system):

F = ma

F = 0.5m/s^2 * 100Kg = 50N

50N / 4 wheels * r = 50 / 4 * 0.125 = 1.5625N-m (Thanks for checking my math Dave)

The circumference of the wheel is pi * 0.25 ~= 0.785m

20km/hr ~= 25478rph ~= 424rpm (shouldn't be a problem for a brushless motor)

So four brushless motors that have this torque in this speed range should nominally meet the requirements.  You would normally take a fairly large margin (e.g. x2).  If you want to drive uphill or over uneven terrain you need to consider gravity.

A good reference for the physics with handy calculators is:
http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hph.html

Comment: @Guy What is 'r' here?

Comment: @Umar r is for radius (1/2 the diameter)